# How can I convert my button into a hyperlink in PHP?

Tags: php, html, button, hyperlink

I need to replace a button on my web page with a hyperlink.
I am calling a PHP script using the button.

I extract the id using the following statement:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

HTML code:

```
<form id="test1" method="post" action="my.php?action=show">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click" onclick="return display(1);" />
</form>
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
 <a href="my.php?action=show&id='1'" onclick="return display(1);"> Click</a>
```

Does my code have a flaw?  Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good, except for three things:

1. Use `&amp;` instead of `&`.
2. Use `id=1` instead of `id='1'`.
3. Use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.  If you want backwards compatibility, you can opt for `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: He should not use &amp; unless he wants the action var to hold: show&id=1. If he wants action=show and id=1 then he should realy use the & and not &amp;

Comment: @Jager, &amp; will be translated into & in the URL.  &amp; is used to escape the & in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the link post the form:

```
<a href="#" onclick="if(display(1))document.getElementById('test1').submit();return false;"> Click</a>
```

That way it works without changing the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

No - looks fine to me, though the '1' doesn't need to be in inverted commas, andy you'll need to change your $_GET to $_POST in your first line of PHP.

Comment: The "inverted commas" are apostrophes.

Comment: Ah - that's the word I was thinking of - wouldn't come to mind for some reason!

Comment: Actually, inverted commas is just as valid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_quotes
And in programming, they're usually referred to as 'single quotes' rather than apostrophes/inverted commas.